# My python code (Quadratic Equation Solver) is not working, any reason why/

Tags: python, python-3.x

This my second python practice program and I have come to an issue.
As the title says, I want to make a quadratic equation solver, but I am facing a problem.

After the code asks me about the A, B, and C values, it doesn't solve it, but rather ask me the same questions again.

Here is the code:

```
import math

def quadratic_solver():

    print("Hello, this code allows the user to solve quadratic equations easily.")

    while True:
        a_value_raw = (input("Please enter the A value: "))
        b_value_raw = (input("Now type in the B value: "))
        c_value_raw = (input("And finally, type the C value: "))

        # This helps to turn user inputs to floats, or it might not help idk.
        a_value = float(a_value_raw)
        b_value = float(b_value_raw)
        c_value = float(c_value_raw)

        discriminant = pow(b_value, 2) - 4 * a_value * c_value

        if discriminant > 0:
            root_1 = str((-b_value + (math.sqrt(pow(b_value, 2)) - 4 * a_value * c_value)) / 2 * a_value)
            root_2 = str((-b_value - (math.sqrt(pow(b_value, 2)) - 4 * a_value * c_value)) / 2 * a_value)
            print("The equation has TWO real roots: ")
            print("Root 1 = " + root_1)
            print("Root 2 = " + root_2)
        else:
            continue

        if discriminant == 0:
            only_root = str((-b_value + (math.sqrt(pow(b_value, 2)) - 4 * a_value * c_value)) / 2 * a_value)
            print("The equation has only ONE root: ")
            print(only_root)
        else:
            continue

        if discriminant < 0:
            print("The equation has NO real roots.")
        else:
            continue


quadratic_solver()
```

Comment: I assume that in all your cases you don't want the `else: continue`

Comment: EDIT: The problem now is that whatever input i give, it always goes to the third condition code which meant to type "The equation has NO real roots."

Comment: Ok, you can't do that here. If you have one problem we can solve it, but you must leave the question there to show how it was solved. If you have another problem after that, then you need to ask a brand new question.

Comment: Ok, now the answers make sense given the original question.

Comment: It still does not work.. bruh

Comment: So you can ask a new question and you should show the improved code and some example inputs and you should say that for all those inputs you get the error print out whereas you were expecting another particular output.

Comment: Ok, except I tried my code with inputs a=1, b=-5, c=6 and it says I have two roots.

Comment: You need to ask a new question and then I'll be able to answer it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to have an `if/elif/else` chain:

```py
        if discriminant > 0:
            root_1 = str((-b_value + (math.sqrt(pow(b_value, 2)) - 4 * a_value * c_value)) / 2 * a_value)
            root_2 = str((-b_value - (math.sqrt(pow(b_value, 2)) - 4 * a_value * c_value)) / 2 * a_value)
            print("The equation has TWO real roots: ")
            print("Root 1 = " + root_1)
            print("Root 2 = " + root_2)
        elif discriminant == 0:
            only_root = str((-b_value + (math.sqrt(pow(b_value, 2)) - 4 * a_value * c_value)) / 2 * a_value)
            print("The equation has only ONE root: ")
            print(only_root)
        else:
            print("The equation has NO real roots.")
```